# How to find the average runtime of this function to be $\theta$(1)

Tags: algorithm, runtime, big-o

def search(lst, x):

```
for item in lst:

  if item == x:

     return True

  return False
```

If the allowed input is a random list of length **n** made up of random elements from {1,2,...10}
How do I prove that the average runtime is big-theta(1)

I've tried so many ways but I keep on getting big-theta(n)

Comment: if `x` is not in the `{1, 2, ..., 10}` range, then `search` should immediately return `False`. if not, the odds `x` is not in the list is `pow(0.9, n)` which tends to zero when `n` is large.

Answer (score 0):

If the random method be uniform, it means that The expected number of 1's in list is n/10, the expected number of 2's is n/10 and so on. Again based on uniform random you expect that find x after checking 10 elements on worst case. So the method has the expected constant time value and the Complexity is Tetha(1).